# TCL Grey Checkbuttons

Tags: tcl

I have been looking through several online resources trying to get my checkbutton to grey out when another button is selected.  However, with all of my attempts, I cannot seem to get it to work.

The following is an example at work:
3 checkboxes called chkAll, chkBalanced, and chkFXO.  Let's say that when chkAll is selected and in the active state then chkBalanced, and chkFXO are then unchecked.  I've tried to use an if-statement that looks at the state of chkAll but it complains about having the state issue in the conditional portion of the block.  Should I consider using variables, if so how do I implement them?  I know that checkbuttons have a -variable option but I also don't really know how to use it

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The behavior you describe sounds like what you need is a "radiobutton" rather than a "checkbutton". And I'm not at all sure what "it complains about having the state issue in the conditional portion of the block" means. Perhaps some specific code or error messages would help.

Comment: So I have a master checkbox called "chkAll" and then there are a group of check boxes below it which are individual tests that are encompassed in the "master" check box.  However, if the user doesn't want to run a full blown test he/she should have the option to select the different test(s) he/she would like to run.  So, if the master check box is selected then presumably all of the individual tests found below it are already included and as such there is no need to select those check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make an exclusive choice, you should not be using checkbuttons. What you are describing is the behavior of radiobuttons.

To use radiobuttons you create two or more and give them all the same variable. You will then only be able to pick one at a time.

```
foreach value {chkAll chkBalanced chkFXO} {
    radiobutton .rb-$value -text $value -variable myvar \
       -justify left -value $value
    pack .rb-$value -side top -fill x -anchor w
}
```

Comment: Best to specify the `-value` option for each as well, rather than relying on a default.

Comment: @DonalFellows: thanks for catching that! Originally I had a tkinter example where I did, then I realized the question was about tcl so I hurredly replaced the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to have three widgets that present a mutually-exclusive choice, for goodness' sake **use radiobuttons** for the task. That's what they're there for. That's what users expect. (Even better, put them in a labelframe; that improves the usability for little effort.)

If you've got something else going on and need to “turn on and off” widgets based on a checkbutton, you do this by putting a write `trace` on the variable referenced by the checkbutton's `-variable` option. That trace should then enable (change to `-state normal`) or disable (change to `-state disabled`) the other widgets when it fires, based on the value of the variable.

```
checkbutton .cb -variable bools(cb) -text "Foo Bar"
button .other -text "Example extra content"
button .widget -text "Second ordinary button"
# NOTE the ;# at the end; IMPORTANT HACK to discard trace arguments
trace add variable bools(cb) {changed bools(cb) .other .widget;#}
proc changed {varName args} {
    upvar "#0" $varName var
    foreach w $args {
        if {$var} {
            $w configure -state normal
        } else {
            $w configure -state disabled
        }
    }
}
set bools(cb) 0;   # <<< Initialize to known state
pack .cb .other .widget
```

This sort of thing can get quite complicated, and produce very nice GUIs. You can also mix it in with radiobuttons (with appropriate adjustments as the state variables are no longer boolean). But don't do it just for simple pick-one-from-a group; use a straight collection of checkbuttons for that.

Comment: I've tried to run your example and got the following >wish test.tcl
Error in startup script: wrong # args: should be "trace add variable name opList command"
    while executing
"trace add variable bools(cb) {changed bools(cb) .other .widget\ ;#}"
    (file "test.tcl" line 5)